# Synchronous console logging in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, logging, webkit

Is it posible to make logging to the console synchronous? I often run into situations where the code execution is faster than dumping the structures. That resolves in outputting already changed objects.

I sure can walk through the code with debugger, make unit tests etc., it's just often convenient to simply `console.log` stuff just to make a general idea of what is going on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could create a copy of the object before passing it to `console.log`. Look [here](http://www.overset.com/2007/07/11/javascript-recursive-object-copy-deep-object-copy-pass-by-value/) for a function to create a deep copy of your object.

**Edit:**

Now implemented in Chrome, see [here](http://blog.chromium.org/2012/10/do-more-with-chrome-developer-tools.html)

Comment: Alright, thanks, that sounds viable. Though I would prefer to just somehow override the original console dumping so it's blocking rather than async.

Comment: The problem is that the object is passed to the console by reference, if you later change the object the output in the console change, too.

Comment: Oh, I see... I thought it does take a snapshot itself. In that case cloning the object seems to be the only solution. Thanks again.

Comment: I played a little bit with the console, it seem to be passed by reference and if you "open" the object the values are evaluated and stay the same.

Comment: Seems you are right. What that console does is one sick behavior I really don't like. I can't think of any situation this would be either helpful or expected. It just seems so silly. Oh well. Thanks, I guess I will have to go with custom wrappers and cloning.

Answer (score 9):

I just got caught by this behaviour, spent some hours until I realized the console is borked, not my code. damn.

Until now I only managed to get expected behaviour with:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

nice side effect is, it expands the objects like {0: "a", 3: "b"}

Comment: Oh that actually fixes everything quite nicely. Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 2):

Put a breakpoint(see image below) at console.log statement and use controls to step over to next.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I know I can walk through the code with the debugger. I've even stated that in the original question.