# console.log a javascript Object/Class - same result before and after the change of the prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype, console.log

I'm trying to understand how `js prototypes` and `classes` work, and I'm using Chrome's `console.log` to print and have a look at the state of my objects while I add new properties etc.

This is the code I'm using: ([**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b4VP3/))

```
function Person(){}

Person.prototype.sayHello = function(){ alert("Hello"); };
Person.prototype.name = "Name";

console.log(Person.prototype) //1st console.log

Person.prototype.surname = "Surname";

console.log(Person.prototype); //2nd console.log
```

I expect to have two different results printed in the console, because the `surname` property was added **after** the first console log. Instead, this is the console output:

[image]

As you can see, both the outputs have the `surname` property defined even if it was added only after the 1st console.log..

Can you explain me why? What am I missing? Doesn't console.log show the current state of the object when called?

Thank you in advance, best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your next line of code where you set the persons surname, doesnt wait for the console log because console.log is asynchrounous, when you try out this code with a timeout it will be correct,

```
 function Person() {}

 Person.prototype.sayHello = function () {
     alert("Hello");
 };
 Person.prototype.name = "Name";

 console.log(Person.prototype) //1st console.log
 setTimeout(function(){
  Person.prototype.surname = "Surname";

 console.log(Person.prototype); //2nd console.log
 },1000);
```

you could save a copy of that object before you log it, then it would work

[Synchronous console logging in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040856/synchronous-console-logging-in-chrome)

UPDATE:
i have an even better solution  :
just log a stringifyed version of the object and you´ll be okay

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(Person.prototype))
```

Comment: have a look at this [this](http://jsfiddle.net/b4VP3/1/) fiddle: if you wait both the console.log before you open the object hierarchy, hte `surname` is present in both.. if you open the 1st object while waiting for the 2nd log, the `surname` is not shown.. why :O?

Comment: hmn for me "surname" is only present in the second log on latest chrome on mac osx

Comment: also if you wait for the second log to appear and then (and only then) you open the Person object?

Comment: as i said, you can just copy the object and log the copied instance, but yes, this is weird :D

Comment: *"your next line of code where you set the persons surname, doesnt wait for the console log because console.log is asynchrounous"* No, `console.log` is not asynchronous. But the console keeps a live reference to the object, and *expanding* the object in the console is asynchronous. Sometimes. Depending on whether the console was open when you logged, amongst other things.